# How to set target and action for UIBarButtonItem at runtime

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uibarbuttonitem

Tried this but only works for UIButton:

```
[btn setTarget:self action:@selector(btnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: That does not appear to be valid even for UIButton.

Comment: For UIButton, the right method is `-addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Just set the UIBarButtonItem's `target` and `action` properties directly.

Comment: N.B. This only works if the `UIBarButtonItem` doesn't use a custom view, like a `UIButton`

Comment: For custom views, use: [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

Comment: Can you please give an example of what those should be set to? The target says it takes an AnyObject? Should that be set to a UIGestureRecognizer?

Comment: assuming btn is a UIBarButtonItem, [btn setTarget:self];
[btn setAction:@selector(btnClicked:)] or DOT notation btn.target = self; btn.action = @selector(btnClicked:);  Both should work as @Ole-Begemann is describing.

Comment: @zmonteca hey, does it still work (6 years later)? how can I set a target and action to a UITabBarItem today?

Comment: @wp42 Should still work. This was just used last year on my end.

Comment: Per the documentation this doesn't work on an instance that has been initialized with a custom view. "The bar button item created by this method does not call the action method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user interactions and provide an appropriate response." See http://apple.co/2egXdmR for reference

Comment: This only works if the UIBarButtonItem doesn't use a custom view

Comment: Did you figure out what worked if you used a custom view?

Comment: For a custom view where you add a UIButton, button, to a UIBarButtonItem, barButtonItem: button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunction), for: .touchUpInside). In other words, add it to the button that you're adding to the barbuttonitem.

Answer (score 28):

UIBarButtonItem doesnt have the same addTarget method so you have to set them directly as follows

```
btn.target = self;
btn.action = @selector(barButtonCustomPressed:);
```

...

```
// can specify UIBarButtonItem instead of id for this case
-(IBAction)barButtonCustomPressed:(UIBarButtonItem*)btn 
{
    NSLog(@"button tapped %@", btn.title);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! this is exactly what i needed to implement my custom UIBarButtonItem class

Comment: great answer, especially if you want to create the buttons at design time!

Answer (score 18):

Set `target` and `action` of your `UIBarButtonItem`

**Swift 5 & 4**

```
button.target = self
button.action = #selector(action)

@objc func action (sender:UIButton) {
    print("action")
}
```

Comment: This only works if the UIBarButtonItem doesn't use a custom view.

Answer (score 15):

I ran into a similar problem... I assume you mean that if your UIButton is not part of your UITabBar to call btnClicked then it works appropriately.  If this is the problem you are proposing then, check your btnClicked method and change it from:

```
-btnClicked:(id)sender
```

to

```
-(void) btnClicked:(id)sender
```

that, and declare btnClicked in the header file...

For what it's worth, this is how I setup a button in tabbarbuttonitem:

```
UIBarButtonItem *exampleButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(btnClicked:)];
```

Comment: additionally, you can take out the ":" making

...:@selector(btnClicked:)]; 

into 

...:@selector(btnClicked)];

Answer (score 9):

If you need this enough times in your code, it's nice to go ahead and extend `UIBarButtonItem` which I've done below in Swift. :)

```
import UIKit

extension UIBarButtonItem {
    func addTargetForAction(target: AnyObject, action: Selector) {
        self.target = target
        self.action = action
    }
}
```

As an example, with self as a `UIViewController`, you'd simply call:

```
self.myBarButtonItem.addTargetForAction(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:))
```

Comment: This is a bad name, it suggests that previous target/actions are preserved as is the case with UIButton

Answer (score 7):

```
UIBarButtonItem *barListBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(getTruckStopListAction)];   
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barListBtn;
[barListBtn release];
```

Answer (score 2):

For a custom `UIBarButtonItem` this works.

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourFunction), for: .touchUpInside)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

You set the target and action to the button that you are adding to your `UIBarButtonItem`.

Answer (score 1):

@wp42 It does work today.

A nifty way of doing this in objective-C is adding a category to UIBarButtonItem class:

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBarButtonItem (addons)

-(void)addTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "UIBarButtonItem+addons.h"

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (addons)

-(void)addTarget:(id)target andAction:(SEL)action{
   [self setTarget:target];
   [self setAction:action];
}

@end
```

In practice:

```
[myBtn addTarget:self andAction:@selector(myFunction:)];
```

Answer (score 1):

For custom views: use an `UITapGestureRecognizer` and set up `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

```
profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleProfileImageTap))
profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileImageView)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are programmatically adding the UIBarButtonItem, the best way to set the target and action is to initialize the button with one of the following methods:

```
UIBarButtonItem *customButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:<#(UIImage)#> style:<#(UIBarButtonItemStyle)#> target:<#(id)#> action:<#(SEL)#>

UIBarButtonItem *customButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:<#(NSString *)#> style:<#(UIBarButtonItemStyle)#> target:<#(id)#> action:<#(SEL)#>

UIBarButtonItem *customButton = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:<#(UIImage *)#> landscapeImagePhone:<#(UIImage *)#> style:<#(UIBarButtonItemStyle)#> target:<#(id)#> action:<#(SEL)#>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5:**

Extract to extensions:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {

    static func nextBtn(target: AnyObject, action: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let title = "Next"
        return button(title: title, target: target, action: action)
    }

    private static func button(title: String, target: AnyObject, action: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        return UIBarButtonItem(title: title, style: .done, target: target, action: action)
    }

}
```

Call in code:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = .nextBtn(target: self, action: #selector(rightBarButtonAction))
```

Action:

```
@objc func rightBarButtonAction() {
    Swift.print("Button tapped!")
}
```

Pretty easy to add new buttons to this factory.

Answer (score -5):

You may want to try out the addTarget method.

Comment: There is no addTarget method for UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: That methohd does not exist, check the docs please: https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html What you are thinking of is a UIButton