# Set an NSButton's action to be the same as an NSMenuItem's

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbutton, nsmenuitem

In my application, I save user preferences and one of the preferences is whether to show any `NSMenuItem`s as buttons in the home window. I don't have problems to create the buttons dynamically, but I can't pass the action of the `NSMenuItem` to the `NSButton`. I have already tried:

```
[newButton setAction:[theItem action]];
```

UPDATE

I just have to set the target as self

```
[newButton setTargert:self];
```

And move the code to the class that send the action to the `NSMenuItem`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following:

1. message selector ([theItem action]) is not NULL.
2. target for the newButton is set.

Comment: I checked, now i know  the problem is that, the button don't recognize the item action. I guess it is because the action of the item is in another object.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the `UIButton` instance's `target` and `action` properties. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2333638/868193) shows how.