# How to set an action for an UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I try to set an action for an UIBarButtonItem like I did before with a normal button:

1. Select the UIBarButtonItem in storyboard.
2. Right-Click and pull to my .h-file
3. Change to action and choose UIBarButtonItem and give the action a name.

   ```
       - (IBAction)haupt:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
   ```
4. Write some code in the function at my .m-file.

   ```
   - (IBAction)haupt:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
       NSLog(@"button");


       }
   ```

Now I try this in the simulator, but nothing happens (No output on the console). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the UIBarButton , Create an IBAction by CNRL+Dragging at the implementation section in .m file then try to print with NSLog use breakpoint to know if the control is reaching the IBAction you created.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you do it with Swift 3:

```
let check: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem()
check.title = "Check"
check.width = CGFloat(100)
check.tintColor = UIColor.green
check.action = #selector(ViewController.checkTapped)
check.target = self

func checkTapped (sender:UIBarButtonItem) {
    print("check pressed")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
myBarButtonItem.target = self;
myBarButtonItem.action = @selector( myMethod: );
```

Remember action method must have the following signature:

```
- ( IBAction )myMethod: ( id )sender;
```

or refer this link : [Add a custom selector to a UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719237/add-a-custom-selector-to-a-uibarbuttonitem)

Comment: Don't forget the column (:) at the end of method in `@selector(myMethod:)` !

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4**:

If you have already create it you can use the `customView` property:

```
barButton.customView?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(barButtonTap)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an Action:

```
[self.myButton setAction:@selector(haupt:)];
```

Or if you are using Storyboard. Right click und pull to you .m file (not .h)

Answer (score 1):

You can use belowed code it is working

```
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
    barButton.title=@"Back";
    [barButton setTarget:self];
    [barButton setAction:@selector(uiBarBurronAction:)];
```

Button Action

```
-(IBAction)uiBarBurronAction:(id)sender
{
        NSLog(@"barbutton Pressed")

}
```

Otherwise you can set selector 
RightClick on uibarbuttonitem and drag selector and give action to viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You ctrl-drag the button to you header file and create an IBOutlet.

Then you wire the button with the IBAction, all good.