# How to get navigationbar barbuttonItem origin in Swift on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, swift4, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

How can I obtain the origin of `UIBarButtonItem` added to `UINavigationBar`, I searched for all question but always find the size instead of frame.

[Get the frame of UIBarButtonItem in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991100/get-the-frame-of-uibarbuttonitem-in-swift/28991219)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Why are you trying to get the origin?

Comment: I need to pass that frame for presenting a view from that button.

Comment: Why you need to pass the frame? Simply attach an action to that button (eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333638/how-to-set-target-and-action-for-uibarbuttonitem-at-runtime)

Comment: @IanBell Thats true but the requirement is too display a userguide from that button without user interaction, and I am using third party framework for displaying userguide where I need to pass view frame.I am even getting the y coordinate by view conversion but x always comes zero.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the frame of the bar button item in the coordinate system of self.view, and then get the origin from that:

```
let barButtonFrame: CGRect? = {
    if let barButtonView = self.barButton.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView {
        return self.view.convert(barButtonView.bounds, from: barButtonView)
    }
    return nil
}()

barButtonFrame?.origin // CGPoint?
barButtonFrame?.size // CGSize?
```

Comment: This does not work for me on iOS 14. It gives some numbers very close to zero that are obviously wrong.